# Cannot open PNGs created with canvas.toDataUrl

Tags: html5-canvas, png, todataurl

I create a png blob from a canvas with the toDataUrl method.

```
const pngdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

I open a text editor and copy the content of `pngdata` into a file that I call `img.png`

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkMAAAiICAYAAAD...
```

I save this file. When I try to open it (Windows 10) I get "It looks like we don't support this file format"

Removing `data:image/png;base64,` from the file doesnt help

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your file is still encoded as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). You need to decode it to actual binary data for it to be a correct binary file.

You can find many online tools that will do this for you, or the best is probably to [directly export your canvas drawing to a binary Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) and download this Blob thanks to a [blob:// URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

Comment: My question was not completely specific, so I comment to explain how this answer helped me. I ended up using the node fs package to save the file and set the encoding to "base64".